# Build variables from properties in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, global-variables

I am trying to build a script to gather the DFSR backlog details of a list of servers.
So far the script will query a text file for a list of servers.
From that list it will use various Powershell commands to determine what replication groups it is a member of and what connections it has. Once I have that data stored in variables I can then use it in dfsrdiag backlog to check the status.

The problem I have is how can I capture and set select properties to variables that I can use to create the dfsrdiag command.

Anyone out there know the best way to select the particular properties and store then to variables in Powershell?

Cheers

Woodsy

Comment: You forgot to post the code so we can help with.

Comment: Hi Abraham,  I have only started playing with the script.  I am trying to find how to set the variable from properties. That would be generic and then I can apply it to the objects I am querying.  I am WFH at the moment so do not have the script available.

Comment: Hi @Woodsy, I have a few suggestions to help your post. At a minimum SO members like to see a [mvce] of your problem code in question, which you haven't included. In addition, "[What is] the best way to do X?" tends to solicit opinion-based answers which is not the right format for this community. I would recommend making an attempt with the code (even if it's not a *great* attempt, at least you tried) and editing that attempt in. I would also reword your "best way" line to focus on any issues in your attempt you run into.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example using `get-service`. You can create an object called $report that contains only the properties you want. You can export `$Report`to a CSV.

All you need to do is apply this to your script.

```
$Services = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.name -like "A*"}

[Array]$Report = foreach ($service in $Services)
{
    [PScustomobject]@{
        Name = $service.DisplayName
        Shortname = $service.name
        Status = $service.Status
        StartType = $service.StartType
    }
}

$Report | select Name, Shortname, Status, StartType
```

Comment: Thanks Judd. I will give it a try next time I am in the Office.

Comment: Thanks Judd had a chance to try that this morning.  and I now can capture the properties I needed.

Comment: Pleasure. Can you mark my answer as correct/helpful.